# Emulate terminal to run ruby code on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, browser, terminal

I want to create a unix terminal on my RoR website. On this terminal, the user should be able to execute ruby code. I have no idea how can I create such terminal on browser.

Can anyone guide me about required resources, available ruby gems and technology to be used?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yep, [`web-console`](https://github.com/rails/web-console) is being integrated into Rails.

Answer (score 0):

you can use backticks to run shell command

```
@resut= `#{cmd}`
```

or `eval` for ruby command

```
@resut=  eval cmd
```

note: those are very dangerous to use in real world app